# Unexpected character/T_STRING error when calling MAXMIND geoip.dat from PHP5 (Windows)

Tags: php, maxmind

I encountered a strange error when trying to call MAXMIND's geoip.dat from their sample PHP script - http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable

```
*Warning*: Unexpected character in input: '
in*C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\clients\geoip\GeoIP.dat*on line*983*
*Parse error*: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
in*C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\clients\geoip\GeoIP.dat*on line*983*
```

Geoip.dat, a binary file, must be downloaded separately from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite.  Note that there's also a CSV version which I did not use.

My code is almost exactly the same as the sample script, except for the paths:

```
<?php

// This code demonstrates how to lookup the country by IP Address

include("GeoIP.dat");

// Uncomment if querying against GeoIP/Lite City.
// include("geoipcity.inc");

$IPaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$gi =
geoip_open("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\clients\geoip\GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $IPaddress) . "\t" .
geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $IPaddress) . "\n";
echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $IPaddress) . "\t" .
geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, $IPaddress) . "\n";

geoip_close($gi);

?>
```

Here's my PHP info output:

```
PHP Version 5.2.6

System  Windows NT 5.2 build 3790
Build Date  May 2 2008 18:01:20
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--with-gd=shared" "--with-extra-includes=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDK\Include;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\ATL\INCLUDE;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\INCLUDE;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\MFC\INCLUDE" "--with-extra-libs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDK\Lib;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\LIB;C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\VC98\MFC\LIB"
Server API  ISAPI
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.ini
PHP API 20041225
PHP Extension   20060613
Zend Extension  220060519
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.zlib, https, ftps
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters   convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower,
```

Comment: Whoever said you're supposed to **`include`** the .dat file?! And if they did, it's nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

`GeoIP.dat` is not a PHP file, so you cannot include it using the `include` statement. Include `geoip.inc` (wherever that is) instead, and your code should work.